# Facebook Integration on server Side

Tags: android, facebook

I was done Facebook integration in my android app,I got token id from login User,Now my Problem is How to Used These Token id to identify particular user on server.I have My own Login Mechanism with Username and password. every user has its own unique id on server.Facebook Login give me basic information,But I want More information Which is on my server.how i identify particular user on server side and return information using Web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user register into your Android app using facebbok, then facebook API will return token and you can store this token in your server's DB. After that, whenever user login using FB you can compare the same token with your remote DB and get related data from remote DB.

Comment: k Sir Can we get user Phone  number through Facebook Integration,Using Graph API.

Comment: yes, we can get the number but it should mark accessible permission by the fb user.  
Also, if my answer is usable marked tick as solved.

Comment: k can u give me more details how to access mobile no.Or some code of getting mobile no

Comment: check sample code from here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/.  just execute http request inside your app

Comment: I already read a lot of forum regarding this issue and the other said the facebook removed the permission to get the mobile or phone number.

So I just asking  is there any way to get it? And one more thing I Cant Understand how UBER and Naukari App Can Get phone no.